# PHP cron job from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, function, cron

Thanks for all the help in advance!

I'm just starting with PHP and currently have to work with existing code; which is over my head.

I have a file filled with functions, which includes this MySQL query:

```
function search_late_orders(){
        $this->assert_connected();
        $this->assert_table_exists(REGION_PREFIX."Order");

        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $sql = "UPDATE `".REGION_PREFIX."Order`
            SET `".REGION_PREFIX."Order`.`orderfulfilled_ts` = `".REGION_PREFIX."Order`.`orderread_ts`
            WHERE `".REGION_PREFIX."Order`.`orderfulfilled_ts` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'";
    }
```

What i'm attempting to accomplish is to reiterate this function every 90 minutes from a different file. The only caveat is that my DB is roughly 60K rows and growing rapidly. What's the best way to accomplish something like this with an eye on performance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to set a default value on `oderfulfilled_ts` like `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` just in the database table? That would make this function superflouus

Comment: I actually need to see the difference in time on orderfulfilled_ts. If I set it to default, then the timing would show 90 minutes but I would prefer for it to show 0. There is a method to this madness, unfortunately.

Comment: Another approach would be to use mysql [events](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html) for that, but as the table name is variable in your program, you need either a timer for each table or a kind of list of tables in the timer.

Comment: Thank you sir. I will implement this approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
0      0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21      *       *       *       /usr/bin/php -q /yourpath/search_late_orders.php
```

you can use crontab to run this task every 90 min

Comment: This website is hosted on Heroku, so I believe I would have to call the function from another php file as I wouldn't have path of the file. Or am I wrong in that assumption?

Answer (score 0):

first install cronie.i dont knw which linux flavour u are using.i am using `centos`

```
yum install cronie
```

as a root.if u know the risk of being a root.if not do it as sudo user
first add `apache` user

```
useradd apache-Apache
```

type `which php` to see path 
    /usr/bin/php

give necessary permission and ownership

```
chown apache /path/to/file
chmod 755 /path/to/file
```

type `crontab -l` to list cronjobs for that user.

now crontab -e to edit or create new jobs as it will open `vi` editor.

```
 * * * * * php /location/of/yourfile/scriptto call
```

add your time in place of star to match your requirement

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however, this app is running on Heroku, unfortunately.